# How can I return from a callback in an Angular5 effect?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

```
  @Effect()   /* sends request to httpService with params as login credentials on instance of loginAction. */
  login$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .instanceOf(LoginActions.LoginAction)
    .switchMap(
      action => {
        return this.loginHttpService.login(action.payload)
          .map( (res: any) => {
            if (res && res.message !== 'Invalid Login') {
                const firstName = res.firstName;
                const lastName = res.lastName;
                this.tokenService.setToken(res.jwt);
                this.tokenService.setFirstName(firstName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + firstName.slice(1));
                this.tokenService.setLastName(lastName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + lastName .slice(1));
                this.tokenService.setId(res.id);
                this.tokenService.setAvatar(firstName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + lastName.charAt(0).toUpperCase());

                const perm = ['ADMIN']
                this.tokenService.setUserRoles(perm)
                return Observable.create(observer => {
                  this.permissionsService.loadPermissions(perm, () => {
                    observer.next({
                      type: 'string'
                    });
                    return observer.complete();

                  })
                })
            }
          }).catch( (e:any)  =>    {
          return Observable.of(new LoginActions.LoginFailureAction(true));
        });
      });
```

I'm trying to return from inside the `loadPermissions`. But I get an error:

```
Effect "LoginEffects.login$" dispatched an invalid action
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to exit the effect without dispatching an action you need to set `disaptach` to `false`. You decorate your effect with `@Effect({ dispatch: false })` and then everywhere you return an Action you need to call `this.store.dispatch(/* Some Action */);` yourself.

```js
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
login$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .instanceOf(LoginActions.LoginAction)
  .switchMap(
    action => {
      this.loginHttpService.login(action.payload)
        .map( (res: any) => {
          if (res && res.message !== 'Invalid Login') {
            // Logic omitted
            this.permissionsService.loadPermissions(perm, () => {
             // Dispatch an action
             this.store.dispatch(new LoginActions.LoginSuccessAction(true)));
            });
          }
        }).catch( (e:any)  =>    {
          this.store.dispatch(new LoginActions.LoginFailureAction(true)));
        });
      });

constructor(private store: Store<any>) {}
```

Comment: Instead of creating a NOOP action, just return `EMPTY` with latest rxjs or `empty()` (if < 6.x from memory)

Comment: But I have the `this.permissionsService.loadPermissions`, which has a callback. How do I dispatch from within the callback?

Comment: Your question didn't state that you were trying to emit an action in the callback. I updated my answer.

Comment: This doesn't work properly. The `Observable.create` function never gets called

Comment: Oh yeah there is no need to do the create anymore since you no longer need to return an observable.